# Is there a shortcut for typing brackets and parenthesis?

Tags: keyboard

1. Is there shortcut for putting `{...}`, `(...)`, or `[...]` around highlighted code (as opposed to typing opening bracket at the beginning and closing bracket at the end)?
2. I have seen people writing code in Mathematica and when they type `{`, `(`, or `[`, it autocompletes by adding a closing the brackets. How do they do that?

Comment: @m_goldberg typing `alt`+`]` causes the selected text to be *replaced* by `[` and `]` (on my machine).  Is there a shortcut that *adds* them around the selected text?

Comment: @m_goldberg, `alt`+`]` results in `[]`. That is, it replaces any selected text with `[]`. That answers part of question 2. Thanks.